# How to achieve a hidden status bar using three20 framework

Tags: iphone, three20, statusbar

I'm using the TTThumbsViewController section of the three20 framework, and I have the status bar hidden throughout my application.

When the user views the full size image, taps the screen(hiding the controls), when they tap again the controls reappear but the status bar is there too.

I've searched through the whole library and been unable to isolate the section where this is happening. I'd love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

BB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it hiding in the UIViewControllerAdditions.m which is called by the TTPhotoViewController.m

```
UIViewControllerAdditions.m

- (void)showBars:(BOOL)show animated:(BOOL)animated {
  //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:!show animated:animated];
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be it whatsoever. Or at least you did not answer your original question. The showBars is not used to show or hide the status bar but rather to show and hide the navigation bar items.

Unless of course you are talking about adding that bit of code you have commented to the showBars. That code does not even appear in my version of Three20 code.

Comment: Tim, it is in the latest version of the `UIViewControllerAdditions.m` file... you can just change `!show` to `YES` as well.